# Get inheritor class name in lazy method of the base class

Tags: c#, oop, generics, static, lazy-initialization

Here the link to a C# fiddle
https://dotnetfiddle.net/4QTGx3

I have tried to retrieve  inheritor class name in static method of the base class. Nothing I have found helps.

```
public class Worker
{
    public string Id1 {get; set;}
    public string Id2 {get; set;}
    public string Id3 {get; set;}
}

public interface IModel
{
}

public class Model1: IModel
{
}

public class Model2: IModel
{
}

public class ModelActor <TModel> where TModel: IModel
{
    private Lazy<Worker> _worker = new Lazy<Worker>(
        () => new Worker() 
        {
            Id1 = new StackFrame().GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name,
            Id2 = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name,
            Id3 = typeof(ModelActor <TModel>).Name
        }
    );

    public Worker Worker
    {
        get
        {
            return _worker.Value;
        }
    }
}

public class ModelActor1: ModelActor<Model1>
{
}

public class ModelActor2: ModelActor<Model2>
{
}

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id1: {0} {1}", new ModelActor1().Worker.Id1,  new ModelActor2().Worker.Id1);
    Console.WriteLine("Id2: {0} {1}", new ModelActor1().Worker.Id2,  new ModelActor2().Worker.Id2);
    Console.WriteLine("Id3: {0} {1}", new ModelActor1().Worker.Id3,  new ModelActor2().Worker.Id3);

    Console.WriteLine("Want to get: ModelActor1 ModelActor2");
}
```

Comment: Other than `Main`, I see no `static`s here. (I'm not sure it's relevant, but you did seem to make a lot of it in the title/initial narrative)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Content of the Lazy constructor cannot contain in-class implemetations. so... static

Answer (score 0):

Okay fixed it. You need to add a second ModelActor class actually because there is only one signature being called.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Program
{

public class Worker
{
    public string Id1 {get; set;}
    public string Id2 {get; set;}
    public string Id3 {get; set;}

    public string ModelName {get; set;}
}

public interface IModel
{
}

public class Model1: IModel
{
}

public class Model2: IModel
{
}

public class ModelActor <TModel> where TModel: IModel
{
    private Lazy<Worker> _worker = new Lazy<Worker>(
        () => {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker Instance created");

                return new Worker() 
                {
                    Id1 = new StackFrame().GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name,
                    Id2 = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name,
                    Id3 = typeof(ModelActor <TModel>).Name,

                    ModelName = typeof(TModel).Name
                };
        }
    );

    public Worker Worker
    {
        get
        {
            return _worker.Value;
        }
    }
}


public class ModelActor2 <TModel> where TModel: IModel
{
    private Lazy<Worker> _worker = new Lazy<Worker>(
        () => {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker Instance created");

                return new Worker() 
                {
                    Id1 = new StackFrame().GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name,
                    Id2 = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name,
                    Id3 = typeof(ModelActor <TModel>).Name,

                    ModelName = typeof(TModel).Name
                };
        }
    );

    public Worker Worker
    {
        get
        {
            return _worker.Value;
        }
    }
}

public class ModelActor1: ModelActor<Model1>
{
}

public class ModelActor2: ModelActor2<Model2>
{
}

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id1: {0} {1}", new ModelActor1().Worker.Id1,  new ModelActor2().Worker.Id1);
    Console.WriteLine("Id2: {0} {1}", new ModelActor1().Worker.Id2,  new ModelActor2().Worker.Id2);
    Console.WriteLine("Id3: {0} {1}", new ModelActor1().Worker.Id3,  new ModelActor2().Worker.Id3);

    Console.WriteLine("Want to get: ModelActor1 ModelActor2\n");

    Console.WriteLine("ModelName: {0} {1}", new ModelActor1().Worker.ModelName,  new ModelActor2().Worker.ModelName);
    Console.WriteLine("No problem with model name.");
}
}
```

Comment: Your case is differ to original question. You are got rid of implementation of Worker in common base class